# Compute total in Excel without resorting to extra column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an Excel file in which different products from e.g. a supermarket are listed and there are two buyers, i.e. John and Mary. Each product is paid by either John, Mary, or both, therefore, some products have to be split between the two people. I have to compute the total for each person and this is the solution that I came up with:
[image]

Column B contains the quantity, column C the price of the product and the "x" in columns D and E indicates who is paying the specific product. As you can see, I am using columns G and H to compute the amount that has to be paid by either John or Mary. I finally compute the total for each person by simply computing the sum of columns G and H.

Is there a more efficient way to compute the total for each person, in particular without using columns G and H? It is still doable for two people but if I have e.g. 20 people involved it can become quite cumbersome.

EDIT: the formula in cell G2 is computed as `=B2*C2/(COUNTA(D2:E2))*COUNTA(D2)`

Answer (score 0):

If instead of `x` you enter the fraction of the amount paid, you can use the `SUMPRODUCT` function to calculate the total.

An example:

[image]

B6: `=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A5;B2:B5)`

C6: `=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A5;B2:B5;C2:C5)`

D6: `=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A5;B2:B5;D2:D5)`

Comment: This is already closer to what I want, but again, it might be inefficient for large groups of people. Suppose that at one point I need to add/remove people on specific products: then I would have to compute the splitting ratios again for all cells. A binary value ("x" or empty cell, "1" or "0") is a more convenient choice for my problem

Comment: @cholo14 Maybe it's an idea to insert an extra column with *number of people paying* and use `1/[amount]` instead of `x`? Still not ideal, but perhaps one step closer.

Comment: @ Berend that's an even better solution, yes. Then I only need an extra column _irrespectively_ of the number of total people, and I can still use `x` to indicate who is paying for every product. I wonder, however, if the totals can be computed in one cell only, without resorting to extra columns. It might not even be possible, I just don't know it

Answer (score 0):

This is an array formula using matrix multiplication. Select D8:H8, type in the formula and CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

```
=MMULT(TRANSPOSE(B2:B7*C2:C7/I2:I7),NOT(ISBLANK(D2:H7))+0)
```

With I2 = COUNTA(D2:H7), dragged down to I7

If you don't want to add the formula in column I, use this

```
=MMULT(TRANSPOSE(B2:B7*C2:C7/MMULT(NOT(ISBLANK(D2:H7))+0,TRANSPOSE(NOT(ISBLANK(D1:H1))+0))),NOT(ISBLANK(D2:H7))+0)
```